# Octave can not read .mat file saved by Matlab

Tags: matlab, octave

I have a .mat file saved previously using Matlab, and the header says it's v5. When Octave opens it with load(), it complains

```
warning: load: can not read non-ASCII portions of UTF characters; replacing unreadable characters with '?'
```

and all the data structure is gone. Dumping out the variable says

```
scalar structure containing the fields:
```

where as when loading with Matlab, the structure is clearly shown.

I opened using Scipy, it looks like this

```
{'__header__': b'MATLAB 5.0 MAT-file, Platform: MACI64, Created on: Sat Aug  4 15:11:49 2018',
 '__version__': '1.0',
 '__globals__': [],
 'doc': <10052x12337 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 139589 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Column format>,
 'embeddings': array([[ 0.25195 , -1.1312  , -0.016156, ..., -0.024497, -0.4867  ,
         -0.42997 ],
        [-0.17686 , -0.60787 ,  0.29096 , ...,  0.13535 ,  0.067657,
          0.073915],
        [ 0.42054 ,  0.39829 ,  0.65161 , ...,  0.19725 ,  0.58798 ,
         -0.04068 ],
        ...,
        [-0.62199 ,  0.74258 , -1.0865  , ...,  0.13148 , -1.2473  ,
          0.34381 ],
        [-0.23951 ,  0.15795 , -0.22288 , ...,  0.50322 , -0.27619 ,
          0.2259  ],
        [-0.21121 , -0.9675  , -0.85478 , ..., -0.59731 , -0.048073,
         -0.63362 ]]),
 'label_names': array([[array(['business'], dtype='<U8'),
         array(['computers'], dtype='<U9'),
         array(['culture-arts-entertainment'], dtype='<U26'),
         array(['education-science'], dtype='<U17'),
         array(['engineering'], dtype='<U11'),
         array(['health'], dtype='<U6'),
         array(['politics-society'], dtype='<U16'),
         array(['sports'], dtype='<U6')]], dtype=object),
 'labels': array([[1],
        [1],
        [1],
        ...,
        [8],
        [8],
        [8]], dtype=uint8),
 'test_idx': array([[ 9868,  9869,  9870, ..., 12335, 12336, 12337]], dtype=uint16),
 'train_idx': array([[   1,    2,    3, ..., 9865, 9866, 9867]], dtype=uint16),
 'vocabulary': array([[array(['manufacture'], dtype='<U11'),
         array(['manufacturer'], dtype='<U12'),
         array(['directory'], dtype='<U9'), ...,
         array(['tufts'], dtype='<U5'), array(['reebok'], dtype='<U6'),
         array(['chewing'], dtype='<U7')]], dtype=object)}
```

I tried rewriting the .mat file using different version numbers, and -nocompress option, but none worked.
How can I resave this data structure using Matlab so that Octave can open it without loss of information?

Comment: Does the data use non-ASCII characters, maybe in field names or variable names? It is kind of hard to debug your issue without any information as to what is in this MAT file, how it was written, etc.

Comment: try saving the file on matlab using an earlier version, e.g. -v7

Comment: is binary. I added the structure in my question. Maybe I should ask a different question. Can I use scipy to save this file so that I can open with Octave?

Comment: I don't see any non-ASCII values in your text data there; that "can not read non-ASCII portions of UTF characters"  warning might be a red herring. What version of Matlab was this file created with? And were you using string arrays or cellstrs for the character data?